# WPF Icon Won't show after install

Tags: wpf, icons

I have a WPF app that has an icon. When I run the program using ctrl + F5 - works great! The icon shows in the task bar. Even if I install it on my local computer that I developed the app on... It still shows.

But, when I install it on a different computer the icon doesn't show in the task bar or anywhere else.

Any ideas on this one? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some specifics - how's the icon used in Xaml?  How is it included in your project?

Comment: Icon="SuperMarioIcon.ico" is an attribute of window. the image ico is in the root of the directory to make it simple.

Comment: pls check if both are using same OS and same resolution, because your icon might contain 32x32 icon only and it may not be running on larger/smaller res box. just a thought. let me know if it helps

Comment: Also, do you have a 48 X 48 icon in your icon file?

Comment: They are both windows 7 machines, and both 64-bit. There is only one ico file though. it's 64x64. It works on mine. Would I need to change this size to something else?

Comment: I'm assuming the icon is part of the project and not just present in the other folders.

Comment: Yes, it's part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you did something along the following lines:

```
<Window Icon="/Resources/MyIcon.ico" ...>
```

If that's the case, make sure to go to the MyIcon.ico file itself and change **Build Action** to `Resource`.

Comment: It is set to Resource and still will not show the icon after install.

Comment: Are you assigning the icon the way I guessed you were or is it being assigned from within the Project Properties?

Comment: I assigned it via the file itself as a build action resource and still no go

Comment: @Blake: What I meant was did you go to the Properties and choose an icon, or did you assign the icon from xaml?